# Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

I'm gettin' these while i analyze my code:

```
Method returns an Objective-C object with a +1 retain count
```

and

```
Object leaked: object allocated and stored into 'headerLabel' is not referenced later in this execution path and has a retain count of +1
```

on this method:

```
 - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
        // create the parent view that will hold header Label
        UIView* customView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(15.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0)];

        // create the button object
        UILabel * headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headerLabel.opaque = NO;
        headerLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        headerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        headerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15];
        headerLabel.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 300.0, 44.0);

        if (section == 0)
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"A", @"A");
        else if (section == 1) 
            headerLabel.text =NSLocalizedString(@"B", @"B");
        else if (section == 2)
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"C", @"C");

        if(searching)
            headerLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"SEARCH", @"Search Results");

        [customView addSubview:headerLabel];

        return customView;
    }
```

Now, expanding the arrows i'm trying to understand, and i *suppose* that customView is not being deallocated. Is it right?

How can i do to fix it? I'm new to this, help me to understand!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either add

```
[headerLabel release];
```

after

```
[customView addSubview:headerLabel];
```

or initialize it like this

```
UILabel * headerLabel = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero] autorelease];
```

of course given that you're not using ARC

Comment: Again, if you're not using ARC, add autorelease to the customView initialization or return [contentView autorelease]; As the viewForHeader method implies that view should be autoreleased.

Comment: Thanks, i tried as you suggested and now it works! No more leaks

Answer (score 1):

```
[customView addSubview:headerLabel];
```

after this line you should release `headerLabel` variable.

> It's important to understand the concept of object ownership. In
>   Objective C, an object owner is someone (or piece of code) that has
>   explicitly said "Right, I need this object, don't delete it". This
>   could be the person (or code) that created the object 
>   . Or it could be another person (or code) that
>   received the object and needs it .
>   Thus an object can have more than one owner. The number of owners an
>   object has, is also the reference count.

Take a look at this [Memory Management with Objective C / Cocoa / iPhone](http://memo.tv/archive/memory_management_with_objective_c_cocoa_iphone).
In your code , you created headerLabel , so you are the owner of that object; you must release that object.

Answer (score 0):

headerLabel should be released and also if your method creates an instance and retains it, it's name has to start with "new", "copy" or "alloc"